# How to move space from 1 file system to another?

Tags: linux, filesystems, virtualbox, gparted

I am currently using Virtualbox to run this server where my current disk space is:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ol-root              50G   44G  6.1G  88% /
devtmpfs                        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           4.0G   80K  4.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           4.0G  9.0M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                           4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                       497M  166M  331M  34% /boot
/dev/mapper/ol-home              26G  2.9G   23G  12% /home
```

I would like to increase the `/dev/mapper/ol-root` size by 12gb. I already increased the size of the .vdi file. Then used gparted to allocate the unallocated space.

However all it's done is massively increase my `ol-home` volume with a bunch of unused space. I'd like to move 12gb of that available space to that of `ol-root`.

Can someone explain how to go about doing this and why gparted added the space to `ol-home` instead?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: I'm using Oracle Linux 7.1.   Basically RHEL